# TypeScript: Error instance for `util.promisify(chpro.execFile)`

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

```js
import chpro from 'node:child_process';
const execFile = util.promisify(chpro.execFile);

try {
  await execFile(
    'doesnotexist',
  );
} catch (error) {
  // 'error' is of type 'unknown'.ts(18046)
  console.log(error.stderr);
}
```

How do I properly do a `error instanceof X` here to so that error is not of type unknown? And so that it contains the `stderr`?

The relevant file for the type is from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/child_process.d.ts but I cannot deduct from that what to do.

It might be that this typing is missing?